# How to stick Contextmenu on particular element

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my Application one of `div` has scroll property.Inside `div`,I templated `table` with more than 100 rows.user can add/delete rows with `contextMenu`

`contextMenu` has 4 options names are `AddTop,AddBottom,Delete and Edit`.The thing is here If user right click on any `row`,`contextMenu` should be stick to that `row` even If user scroll the table.Right now It's not happening.

I written following code for `contextMenu`.

```
 <div id="contextMenu" class="dropdown clearfix">
            <ul class="dropdown-menu-r" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
                <li id="addTop"><a tabindex="-1" href="#"> <span class="new-icons new-icons-add-top"></span> Add Top</a></li>
                <li id="addBottom"><a tabindex="-1" href="#"> <span class="new-icons new-icons-add-bottom"></span> Add Bottom</a></li>
                <li id="delete"><a tabindex="-1" href="#"><span class="new-icons new-icons-delete"></span> Delete</a></li>
                <li id="edit"><a tabindex="-1" href="#"><span class="new-icons new-icons-edit2"></span> Edit</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

once user rightclick on any row of the `table`.following function will run.

```
var domEle=document.getElementById("contextMenu"),
    xPosition=event.pageX,
    yPosition=event.pageY;
domEle.style.display="block";
domEle.style.left=xPosition+"px";
domEle.style.top=yPosition+"px";
```

After completion of the following function,`contextMenu` coming untill it's fine.The problem is If I scroll `contextMenu` not sticking to that particular position.

I hope,you guys understand What I am trying to explaining.

can anyone help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try implement your code with something like that:

http://www.pixelbind.com/make-a-div-stick-when-you-scroll/